# How to use 2 expressions in EF Repository Pattern

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern

I have this method in my Generic EF Repository class

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllByExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression,
        Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes) where T : class
    {
        if (expression != null)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = context.Set<T>();
            foreach(var include in includes)
            {
                query = query.Include(include);
            }

            var result = await query.Where(expression)
                .ToListAsync();

            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Invalid expression.");
        }
    }
}
```

I do not know how to use the "Include" to it. Basically what I want to get is like this =>

```
return await context.PropertyChargesRates.Where(x => x.BuildingId == buildingId)
                    .Include(x => x.PropertyChargeType)
                    .ToListAsync();
```

This is how I try to utilize this function:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<PropertyChargesRate>> GetPropertyChargeRates(int buildingId)
        {
            try
            {
                var g = new GenericRepository<PropertyChargesRate>(context);
                var result = g.GetAllByExpression<PropertyChargesRate>(x => x.BuildingId == buildingId, ** CANT FIGURE OUT HOW TO CALL THIS PART YET **);

                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementation that you are looking for could look like this:

```
        public IEnumerable<T> GetAllByExpression<T>(
         YourDBContext  context,
         Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression,
         Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>> includes) where T : class
    {
        if (expression != null)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = context.Set<T>();
            query = includes(query);

            var result = query.Where(expression)
                              .ToList();
            return result;
        }

        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression), "Invalid expression.");
    }
```

And usage would look like this:

```
repository.GetAllByExpression<YourEntity>   
         (YourDbContext,
         YourWhereExpression,
         (q)=> q.Include(i=> i.YourInclude1)
                .Include(i2=> i2.YourInclude2));
```